# Silently uninstall bloatware

Tags: windows, uninstall, cleanup

The company I work at goes through computers fairly regularly. When we get a new computer, someone has to manually go through and remove all the bloatware that comes with the computer. Right now, I am compiling a database of known bloatware and their silent uninstall commands, but many programs either don't have or require a silent uninstall script to be created. I'm wondering if there are any methods that I have missed that would silently reduce the windows installation to just the barebones OS and drivers.

Comment: As Lucas said. However, if you've got a decent list of how to uninstall crapware consider publishing it to a forum or site - there's probably a number of people that would appriciate it.

Comment: As Lucas said. However, why are you buying computers from a vendor who installs software you don't want in the first place?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Are there any who **don't**? Even when buying HPs and Dells through our corporate account at my last job, they still had a lot of crap on them out of the box. Not quite as much as a consumer desktop, but still a lot more crap than a clean install.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's called a format. Just use a PXE server with some windows images. When a new computer comes in you automatically install a new windows image on it. In my experience, that's the easiest way.

Comment: Totally agree, even when you uninstall that bloatware there are all sorts of little artifacts that can cause issues not the least of which is potentially leave security risks.

Comment: I'd +2 that if I could. Perfect answer.

Comment: besides bloatware you more then likely to have the virus of the day delivered by your friendly pc provider!

Comment: What to do with the 'free' Windows license your friendly OEM provides you with?

Comment: @MartijnHeemels http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/buying-a-dell-without-windows-is-not-easy-but-possible-20101228/ Why do you need an OS on a prebuilt computer?

Comment: @MartijnHeemels Some of the MS volume licensing arrangements require the purchase of the OEM license with the system in order to use the volume key.

Comment: @ShaneMadden yep, most available to .edu customers do, for example.

Comment: @Martijn, this process can be used with OEM licenses as well, although you will need to configure it to prompt for the OEM key.

Comment: Thanks, do you know a good guide with best practices? Furthermore, how does licensing work?

Comment: There is a guide over here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722358(v=ws.10).aspx . But like a previous user said, some OEM's will install a custom image for you. Also you already have a license from your OEM, so you can just use those keys (often found on a label on the computer) to install your software. Don't forget to accept the answer if it was useful by clicking the 'V' ;) Good Luck!

Answer (score 10):

Lucas's answer is the best way to go but if you have a situation where that's not practical you can create a machine image using an OEM install of Windows, customised to your liking. Give a copy of that image to your OEM supplier and instruct them to use it for all future PC purchases. If the supplier won't agree to do that find a supplier who will work *with* you.

Answer (score 3):

[PC Decrapifier](http://pcdecrapifier.com/) is actually pretty good for this.

Comment: But you would still need to run and select everything manually no?